# A UEFI entry is corrupt. How do I fix it?

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, efi

I uninstalled Windows 10 from my triple boot setup to be left with dual boot but the UEFI entry for it stayed after I removed the drive, so to remove it I used `easyUEFI` to remove the entry but it just comes back and does not really get removed. When I look at my entries using `efibootmgr` it is all garbled up and when I open my boot menu, one line is extremely long and the graphics is messed up (see picture).

So I wanted to remove the Windows 10 entry using `efibootmgr` because it might be better however it is garbled up.

Pictures:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Why did you remove the pictures? They’re essential information. // There’s also nothing wrong with the Windows Boot Manager entries. All you need to remove them is the ID (`0000` and `0008`).